# Entity Framework 6 Query Performance (M-M Relationship)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

I need to query multiple columns from multiple tables using EF. All goes well and with nice performance when i don't include a M-M Relationship in the select query.

Query with M-M Relationship:

```
result = (from s in db.Member
                      .Include(i => i.Category)
                      .Include(i => i.MemberWorkEntity)
                      .Include(i => i.Status)
                      .Include(i => i.DiscountMethod)
                      .Where(i => i.C_deleted == null)
      select new MemberDTO
      {
          memberNumber = s.memberNumber,
          name = s.name,
          status = s.Status.name,
          email = s.email,
          phone = s.phone,
          mobile = s.mobile,
          fax = s.fax,
          workEntity = (from e in db.WorkEntity.Where(i => i.workEntityLevelID == 2)
                        join sc in s.MemberWorkEntity on e.workEntityID equals sc.workEntityID
                        select e.name).FirstOrDefault(),
          category = s.Category.name,
          discountMethod = s.DiscountMethod.name,
          delegate = s.delegate ? "Yes" : "No",
          leader = s.leader ? "Yes" : "No"

      }).AsNoTracking().ToList<MemberDTO>();
```

30000 records execution time (ms):

```
|1st Execution: 1376
|2nd Execution: 160
|3rd Execution: 145
```

Query without M-M Relationship:

```
result = (from s in db.Member
                      .Include(i => i.Category)
                      .Include(i => i.MemberWorkEntity)
                      .Include(i => i.Status)
                      .Include(i => i.DiscountMethod)
                      .Where(i => i.C_deleted == null)
      select new MemberDTO
      {
          memberNumber = s.memberNumber,
          name = s.name,
          status = s.Status.name,
          email = s.email,
          phone = s.phone,
          mobile = s.mobile,
          fax = s.fax,
          //removed M-M Relationship Query
          category = s.Category.name,
          discountMethod = s.DiscountMethod.name,
          delegate = s.delegate ? "Yes" : "No",
          leader = s.leader ? "Yes" : "No"

      }).AsNoTracking().ToList<MemberDTO>();
```

30000 records execution time (ms):

```
|1st Execution: 1286
|2nd Execution: 79
|3rd Execution: 67
```

Why such a difference (2x slower in average)? How can i improve the query performance?

**UPDATE: Relationship between Member and WorkEntity**
[image: M-M Relationship]

**UPDATE: Updated my query based on @AndreFilimon's suggestion:**

```
IEnumerable<WorkEntity> workEntities = db.WorkEntity.AsNoTracking().Where(i => i.workEntityLevelID == 2);

result = (from s in db.Member
                      .Include(i => i.Category)                          
                      .Include(i => i.Status)
                      .Include(i => i.DiscountMethod)
                      .Where(i => i.C_deleted == null)
      select new MemberDTO
      {
          memberNumber = s.memberNumber,
          name = s.name,
          status = s.Status.name,
          email = s.email,
          phone = s.phone,
          mobile = s.mobile,
          fax = s.fax,
          workEntity = (from e in workEntities
                        join sc in s.MemberWorkEntity on e.workEntityID equals sc.workEntityID
                        select e.name).FirstOrDefault(),
          category = s.Category.name,
          discountMethod = s.DiscountMethod.name,
          delegate = s.delegate ? "Yes" : "No",
          leader = s.leader ? "Yes" : "No"

      }).AsNoTracking().ToList<MemberDTO>();
```

30000 records execution time (ms):

```
|1st Execution: 1364
|2nd Execution: 122
|3rd Execution: 120
```

**UPDATE: Added a simple index to my Member table as @agfc suggested:**

```
IEnumerable<WorkEntity> workEntities = db.WorkEntity.AsNoTracking().Where(i => i.workEntityLevelID == 2);

result = (from s in db.Member
                      .Include(i => i.Category)                          
                      .Include(i => i.Status)
                      .Include(i => i.DiscountMethod)
                      .Where(i => i.C_deleted == null)
      select new MemberDTO
      {
          memberNumber = s.memberNumber,
          name = s.name,
          status = s.Status.name,
          email = s.email,
          phone = s.phone,
          mobile = s.mobile,
          fax = s.fax,
          workEntity = (from e in workEntities
                        join sc in s.MemberWorkEntity on e.workEntityID equals sc.workEntityID
                        select e.name).FirstOrDefault(),
          category = s.Category.name,
          discountMethod = s.DiscountMethod.name,
          delegate = s.delegate ? "Yes" : "No",
          leader = s.leader ? "Yes" : "No"

      }).AsNoTracking().ToList<MemberDTO>();
```

30000 records execution time (ms):

```
|1st Execution: 1544
|2nd Execution: 109
|3rd Execution: 105
```

**UPDATE: Changed query based on @Klinger's answer:**

```
result = db.MemberWorkEntity.Where(mw => mw.WorkEntity.workEntityLevelID == 2 && mw.Member.C_deleted == null)
        .Select(s => new MemberDTO 
        {
            memberNumber = mw.Member.memberNumber,
            name = mw.Member.name,
            status = mw.Member.Status.name,
            email = mw.Member.email,
            phone = mw.Member.phone,
            mobile = mw.Member.mobile,
            fax = mw.Member.fax,
            workEntity = mw.WorkEntity.name,
            category = mw.Member.Category.name,
            discountMethod = mw.Member.DiscountMethod.name,
            @delegate = mw.Member.@delegate ? "Yes" : "No",
            leader = mw.Member.leader ? "Yes" : "No"
        }).ToList();
```

30000 records execution time (ms):

```
|1st Execution: 1427
|2nd Execution: 80
|3rd Execution: 76
```

Comment: You're including a sub-query with a join inside a projection, naturally it will get slower

Comment: You don't have a direct navigation between Member.MemberWorkEntity and the WorkEntity? (can you add one ?), you should avoid running that join query inside the select, cause it will run in a loop for each selected item.

Comment: @Tuco naturally it gets slower, my question is what changes can i make to my query for it to be faster.

Comment: I would ask the same as @AndreiFilimon

Comment: @AndreiFilimon what do you mean with "direct navigation between Member.MemberWorkEntity and the WorkEntity". MemberWorkEntity is the result table between Member and WorkEntity (M-M Relation).

Comment: Can you do something like: workEntity = s.MemberWorkEntity.WorkEntity.Name? instead of doing that query?

Comment: the tables Member and WorkEntity relationship [link](https://s15.postimg.org/d29piduuz/m_m.jpg)

Comment: @AndreiFilimon i can only do this: s.MemberWorkEntity.Where(i => i.workEntityLevelID == 2).FirstOrDefault().WorkEntity.name; not much difference regarding the execution time.

Comment: I have updated the answer have a look, moved out the inner query to avoid so many joins.You might need to tweak it a little, I'm blind coding it.

Comment: Why do you include `MemberWorkEntity`? It looks like an uninteresting junction table.

Comment: Sub queries is a major performance drain. Try refactoring your query to use GroupJoin which should generate Cross Apply on the SQL server (are you using SQL serve) side  , which will be quicker. Also, do you have all the proper indexes on the DB?

Comment: @gertarnold i removed the MemberWorkEntity include. in my code i did have it. my mistake.

Comment: @agfc i'm using SQL Server and i added a simple index to the primary key. i did get some better performance. updated my question with another test. regarding GroupJoin, can you explain how i can use it in my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at the exact shape of your entities, something like the following should do:

```
result = db.MemberWorkEntity.Where(mw => mw.WorkEntity.workEntityLevelID == 2 && mw.Member.C_deleted == null)
        .Select(s => new MemberDTO 
{
  memberNumber = mw.Member.memberNumber,
  name = mw.Member.name,
  status = mw.Member.Status.name,
  email = mw.Member.email,
  phone = mw.Member.phone,
  mobile = mw.Member.mobile,
  fax = mw.Member.fax,
  workEntity = mw.WorkEntity.name,
  category = mw.Member.Category.name,
  discountMethod = mw.Member.DiscountMethod.name,
  @delegate = mw.Member.@delegate ? "Yes" : "No",
  leader = mw.Member.leader ? "Yes" : "No"
}).ToList();
```

No need to use `Include` because you are projecting into a DTO not an entity. The DTO won't have the navigation properties to the entities you are including. `Include` is used for eager loading when entities are returned.

Comment: @kilinger thanks for your answer. i tested your solution but i had an increase on the results: 1st Execution: 1551ms, 2nd Execution: 175ms, 3rd Execution: 172.

Comment: @Ricky Just so I know what to look for, which one is the correct one, with or without collection? 1st or second query.

Comment: the correct one is the one with the collection. i had to make some changes in order for it to return the correct result: 1st: s.MemberWorkEntity.WorkEntity.workEntityLevelID == 2 // 2nd: workEntity = s.MemberWorkEntity.FirstOrDefault(mw => mw.workEntityLevelID = 2 && mw.memberNumber == s.memberNumber).WorkEntity.name

Comment: @Ricky How about now?

Comment: @Ricky With the caveat that this query only returns Members that are related to a row on MemberWorkEntity

Comment: humm, the result is returning all the registered members. i think that a member will always belong to at least one WorkEntity, so that's fine. nonetheless, i'll be aware of that during the application development.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the includes after the where clause, you should get some overall performance here also:
Also move the inner query out of the main query to avoid joins as bellow:

```
var workEntities=(from e in db.WorkEntity).Where(e=>e.workEntityLevelID==2).ToList();
var result = (from s in db.Member.Where(i => i.C_deleted == null).Include(i => i.Category).Include(i => i.MemberWorkEntity).Include(i => i.Status).Include(i => i.DiscountMethod)
          select new MemberDTO
          {
              memberNumber = s.memberNumber,
              name = s.name,
              status = s.Status.name,
              email = s.email,
              phone = s.phone,
              mobile = s.mobile,
              fax = s.fax,
              workEntity = workEntities.Where(e=>e.workEntityID ==sc.workEntityID).DefaultIfEmpty().Select(e=>e.name).FirstOrDefault(),
              category = s.Category.name,
              discountMethod = s.DiscountMethod.name,
              delegate = s.delegate ? "Yes" : "No",
              leader = s.leader ? "Yes" : "No"

          }).AsNoTracking().ToList<MemberDTO>();
```

Comment: i modified the query based on your suggestion and the performance increased a little but not much: 1st Execution: 1478ms, 2nd Execution: 147ms, 3rd Execution: 122. What else can i try?

Comment: Post the models so I can see how the navigations are defined between them, you shouldn't need that sub-query, if the models have properly defined navigation properties.

Comment: i placed the workEntities query outside and updated the result query to:
(from e in workEntities
join sc in s.MemberWorkEntity on e.workEntityID equals sc.workEntityID
select e.name).FirstOrDefault(),
but now i get the following error: "Unable to create a constant value of type 'Domain.Model.WorkEntity'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Comment: nevermind, i've got the query working. i've updated my question with your solution.

Comment: Both suggestions don't make sense. 1. You can't use a local sequence of objects (`workEntities`) in an EF query. 2. The position of the `Includes` doesn't make any difference. Please try your solutions before posting them. This only deludes future readers. I recommend deletion.